# Failure when calling my bean method in JSF action handler

Tags: jsf

I need to call/execute a method from my bean in JSF 2.2. At 1st glance nothing special here but i can't figure out why bean method wasn't called.
Part of the bean:

```
    @Component
    @Scope("request")
    public class Dock{
    public void someLogic(){
     /// some logic;
    }
```

Part of xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<ui:define name="title">
   some title
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="body">
<h:form id="ttt" onsubmit="return false;">
   <h:commandButton id="call" type="button"
     action="#{dock.someLogic}" >
   </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

i make a call using the following snippet: `document.getElementById("ttt.call").click()`

So i issue a 'click' event and the 'ttt.call' h:commandButton should be 'pressed' as i can assume but nothing happens. I didn't see any related errors neither in browser console nor in my server logs. BTW in my form i make 'return false' in 'onsubmit' handler to avoid reloading of the webpage - this is the mandatory requirement. Actually I need to make only method call on JS click without any side effects. Is it possible? So what should i do to make my method call work? Maybe some additional information needs to be provided?

Thanx in advance for any assist.

Comment: Re. your original question/tags: You wasn't using JSP. You're using Facelets (XHTML). And you also wasn't really using Ajax (although that would have been the solution to your double submit issue).

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your suggestions!